# Cannot get download url for imageview in cell

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase

I am having a problem at the moment, I have hooked up firebase to my app, created users able to post images to firebase, and to loop through posts to find the following users to create a feed. Only one problem, a tutorial I have been following to make the feed section, includes a void = downloadurl(with: String) and I cannot find this function. I have imported the same modules and app is nearly cloned to his. I am quite confused and was hoping someone could help out. Here is the collectionview cell at the moment:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return posts.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", 
for: indexPath) as! UserFeedCollectionViewCell

->   cell.myImage. downloadImage(from: String)   <- does not exist, or 
doesn't show up. 
cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true

return cell
```

}

The youtube tutorial is this link: https://youtu.be/fw7ySRFtX_M 
and at exactly 35 minutes he shows you how to download the cell image. I have code for creating the feed, but this code is not imortant, and I have firebase and uikit imported.
Please give any tips if you can! Thank You (:

Comment: Try watching episodes 1,2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for the `downloadImage` function. It is an extension of UIImageView. The extension should be placed outside of any classes.

```
class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // deleted to save space
}

extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a built-in function or anything that is innate to Firebase or iOS. In the video, the author mentions that he created this function in his previous video, so you should probably find his previous video and/or download the final project to see what he did.

(There are also lots of great third party library like [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) that provide some similar tools for you -- you might want to look at one of them, as well.)

Comment: Thank you very much